# Month Dependent Text in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a bit of test that needs to only appear on my site during the months of Aug through Nov, and all other months the text should be something different. What is the best way to accomplish this?

I would think it would look something like the following, but I am not sure how to limit it to just the month, so that the switch will happen every year.

```
IF Date.today IS BETWEEN ???August AND ???Nov DO
  ...
ELSE
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.month` and check if it's value included into expected list of accepted months

```
accepted_months = Set.new([8, 9])

if accepted_months.include?(Time.current.month)

else

end
```

Comment: Do I put `accepted_months` declaration in the page code or is it best in another file?

Comment: You can put it anywhere you found it be expected place. You can make it constant. If not sure put closer to the place where it is used, and move it later into different if you find better place.